# What are Dynamics NAV licensing requirements for Web Services?

Tags: web-services, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav, microsoft-dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2016

This post refers to SOAP and OData Web Services in Dynamics NAV 2016 (or later) and hopefully it is not off-topic. I would like to know whether the following facts are **true or false** (or it depends).

Given **Starter Pack** functionality, and default **Customer License** with no extra **Development Granules**:

1. A **Full User** can publish any page (say, *Customer* or *Employee*) as a Web Service.
2. When consuming a published Web Service from another software service, a separate NAV user *should* be created and **not be associated with a real person** - and this is fine with respect to NAV's licensing (e.g. *Perpetual Licensing* with *Concurrent Client Access Licenses*).
3. A Full User can create a **codeunit** (in the allowed range of 10 codeunits for the Starter Pack) and publish the code unit as a Web Service.
4. Both a Full User and a Limited User can be used to authenticate against a Web Service.

In other words, I would like to know to which extent is a customer of Starter Pack (no extra Development Granules) able to integrate NAV with other software systems via SOAP / OData endpoints - without relying on the elevated development capabilities of a *Certified Partner* / *Value Added Reseller*.

[Microsoft Dynamics NAV 2016 Product Overview and Capability Guide](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49484)

[Walkthrough: Registering and Using a Page Web Service (SOAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd355316(v=nav.90).aspx)

[MS Dynamics NAV - development licensing basics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012723/ms-dynamics-nav-development-licensing-basics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon cross-posting on dedicated Dynamics forums ([Dynamics NAV Users](https://dynamicsuser.net/nav/f/developers/90707/what-are-dynamics-nav-2016-licensing-requirements-for-web-services) and Dynamics Community), I reached the following conclusions:

1. True.
2. True, but must be aware of licensing issues related to multiplexing. [Multiplexing](https://dynamicsuser.net/nav/b/kine/posts/nav-2013-2015-session-counting) is not allowed. More comments about Web Services and internal / external users are [here](https://dynamicsuser.net/nav/f/developers/90707/what-are-dynamics-nav-2016-licensing-requirements-for-web-services).
3. Partially true. A Developer License is required to create new codeunits - a Customer License doesn't suffice. Existing codeunits can be published as Web Service though.
4. True.